# Nonce-Attribute is empty in webkit browsers?

Tags: content-security-policy, nonce

I have a strange behavior in my code, but its only appears in webkit browsers (chrome + opera) and only with SSL enabled. General I use nonce-attribute in script-tags, but only a special usergroup send the matching http-header for nonce. So for most visitors its only a attribute and not for security.

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/script.js" nonce="random-value"></script>
```

On localhost without SSL (only HTTP) its working fine, but with SSL (HTTPS) I see in source code the random-value but in inspector/elements is nonce-attribute empty.

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/script.js" nonce=""></script>
```

In Firefox and Edge its show this value. Is this a bug or for security in webkit or my mistake, but why only in webkit? Chrome 68.0.3440.84 with Windows 10.

Comment: Chrome uses the Blink engine, (part of Chromium). WebKit is used by Safari. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(web_engine)

Comment: It might help to show the code you’re using to generate the meta tag, including the conditional that only shows it for some people